# How to print a docx to a specific (non-default) printer in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, printing

I have been exploring how to print a document to a specific printer in an automated fashion. Unfortunately, all I could find in my research was how to change the default printer, then print, then switch the default printer back.

Occasionally, somehow the default printer doesn't switch back to the original default printer and that causes the document to be printed out on the wrong paper.

Is there a way to only print to a specific printer using

- win32api
- win32print

I'm also open to other methods not using these libraries.

Here is my code:

```
length = len(win32print.EnumPrinters(2))

for i in range(0,length):
if win32print.EnumPrinters(2)[i][2] == "ZDesigner GX430t":
    zebra_printer = win32print.EnumPrinters(2)[i][2]
    win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(zebra_printer)
    win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", filename, None,  ".",  0)

for i in range(0,length):
if win32print.EnumPrinters(2)[i][2] == "Brother MFC-9340CDW Printer":
    brother_printer = win32print.EnumPrinters(2)[i][2]
    win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(brother_printer)
```

I have tried using the win32api and win32print libraries and have been unsuccessful in getting it to print to a different printer without changing the default printer then printing then changing back the default printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [pywin32 docs](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html#shellexecute) you can specify printer with the `win32.ShellExecute`:

```
import tempfile
import win32api
import win32print

filename = tempfile.mktemp (".txt")
open (filename, "w").write ("This is a test")
win32api.ShellExecute (
  0,
  "print",
  filename,
  #
  # If this is None, the default printer will
  # be used anyway.
  #
  '/d:"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter (),
  ".",
  0
)
```

I can confirm that it works quite well.

Comment: Thanks!  I had looked at this previously but deleted the '/d:"%s"' before pointing to the printer.

It works when you replace "win32print.GetDefaultPrinter ()," with the name of the printer.