# Python Printer Access Denied

Tags: python, windows, automation, printing

I am trying to use this code to set up a printer automation. I'm still figuring out how win32 works so let me know if you have any idea on what I could do better overall!

```py
import win32api
import win32print

name = "Microsoft Print to PDF"

printdefaults = {"DesiredAccess": win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS}
handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(name, printdefaults)

level = 2
attributes = win32print.GetPrinter(handle, level)
# print(attributes)

win32print.SetPrinter(handle, level, attributes, 0)
win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(name)
win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'print', 'test.pdf', None, '.', 0)

win32print.ClosePrinter(handle)
```

This code throws me the `pywintypes.error: (5, 'OpenPrinter', 'Access Denied')`  error.

If I use `win32print.PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER` instead of `win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS` for the DesiredAccess it throws the same error and when I use `win32print.PRINTER_ACCESS_USE` it throws me a `pywintypes.error: (5, 'SetPrinter', 'Access Denied')` error.

Comment: What is the actual goal of the script? If you just want to print to the desired printer, you can do that without changing its properties: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77029359/11481315

Comment: @viilpe i need to be able to change the properties. I have no clue how to get around the Access Denied.